# AngularJS nested ng-if not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

Not certain why but I can't get this nested ng-if to work.  I am printing to console the $scope value so I can see its correct, but the html is not showing.

I am essentially using $scope.vars to display/hide certain sections of the page based on buttons at the top.  Three buttons

Editing my original posted code:

```
  // when the user lands on the page, the screen defaults to button1 DIVs
$scope.screenInfo.rlScreen = 1 ;
$scope.screenInfo.crDone = 0 ;
$scope.screenInfo.prDone = 0 ;

  $scope.rlShow = function(screen) {
    $scope.screenInfo.rlScreen = screen ; 
    if (screen == 3) {
      var page1 = getSomething("current") ;
      $scope.crData= page1.data ;
      $scope.crRowSize = page1.rowCount ;
      $scope.crStatus = page1.status ;
      $scope.screenInfo.crDone = page1.done ;
    } else if (screen == 4) {
      var page2 = getSomething("past") ;
      $scope.prData = page2.data ;
      $scope.prRowSize = page2.rowCount ;
      $scope.prStatus = page2.status ;
      $scope.screenInfo.prDone = page2.done ;

    }
  }

////// HTML below

<div> <!-- these buttons are always present at the top of the page -->
  <button id="button1" ng-click="rlShow(1);">1 </button> 
  <button id="button2"  ng-click="rlShow(3);">3 </button>
  <button id="button3" ng-click="rlShow(4);">4 </button> 
</div>

<div ng-if="screenInfo.rlScreen==1">  <!-- works by default -->
   Default page...shows user options to select then submit
   <button id="button2" ng-click="rlShows(2);">2 </button>
</div>

<div ng-if="screenInfo.rlScreen==2">  <!-- works when button2 is clicked -->
  <div ng-if="returnedData.length==0">
    <img ng-src="img/loading_circles.gif"><br>retrieving information...
  </div>
  <div ng-if"returnedData.length > 0">
      The following items were found:
      ...
  <div>
</div>
<div ng-if="screenInfo.rlScreen==3"> <!-- only this DIV works, no childs work -->
   Test vars just to see what is making it into screenInfo.rlScreen==3
   <br>A: {{screenInfo.crDone}}
   <br>B: {{parent.screenInfo.crDone}}
   <br>C: {{$parent.screenInfo.crDone}}
  <div ng-if="screenInfo.crDone==0">
    <img ng-src="img/loading_circles.gif"><br>retrieving information...
  </div>
  <div ng-if"screenInfo.crStatus==0">
      Nothing found
  </div>
  <div ng-if"screenInfo.crStatus > 0">
      The following items were found:
      ...
  <div>
</div>

<div ng-if="screenInfo.rlScreen==4"> <!-- only this DIV works, no childs work -->
  <div ng-if="screenInfo.prDone==0">
    <img ng-src="img/loading_circles.gif"><br>retrieving information...
  </div>
  <div ng-if"screenInfo.prStatus==0">
      Nothing found
  </div>
  <div ng-if"screenInfo.prStatus > 0">
      The following items were found:
      ...
  <div>
</div>
```

In the above code, the user lands on screen1 by default, the user sees the form/options and clicks the button2, screenInfo.rlScreen==2 kicks in, the "cirlces" appear while data is being retrieved and when the data is returned the cirlces go away and either of the two remaining conditions is met and displays the correct info - this all works.

However, if the user clicks on Button3 or Button4 at the top, I can see in the console that screenInfo.rlScreen==3 (or 4) is activated, but the subsequent screenInfo.crDone==0 or screenInfo.prDone==0 never triggers nor does any of the remaining ng-ifs to display content ever appear.

In the screenInfo.rlScreen==3 (or 4) I have tested for a variety of conditions, the A:, B: and C:...all of which just show:

```
A: 
B: 
C:
```

Comment: Hmmm, if I changed the nested ng-if to ng-show then it works.  def must be a ng-if child issue, but even using `$parent.screenInfo.crDone` didn't work.

Comment: can you show more code here demonstrating this not working?  This HTML seems to work fine:  http://plnkr.co/edit/v249foq3tkD7ul24QYKZ?p=preview

Comment: @Claies - reworked original posting, entire problem/code now present.  For the record....inside of the `screenInfo.rlScreen == x`, instead of doing nested ng-ifs, I used ng-show and the same problem persisted, the only different though is ng-show added the DIVs to the DOM but just had them hidden because the values never matched the condition.  Which is telling me even the ng-show is somehow bound to the same nested $scope of the original ng-if.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is why in this bit of code I am experiencing this nested ng-if issue...I have plenty of other sections of code that have nested ng-if...two, three deep yet in those I am doing nothing special and accessing everything from the parent scope with the same {{thisVarName}} or {{ objName.thisKeyName}}

Comment: What does `getSomething` do?  This code is still not a [mcve];  it works when you hardcode all the values in the `rlShow` function and omit the `page` variables.  Are you **sure** that `getSomething` is returning what you expect?

Comment: @Claies - well, your comment "are you sure that getSometing is returning" got me looking again.  It is returning, and returning the correct data...except that I didn't have it properly bound to a promise...so the asynchronous aspect of JS got me.  I bound the service to a promise and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `ng-if` creates its own scope. As such, you'll end up creating a property `screenInfo.crDone` on this new inner scope.  You'll be able to access the correct scope property using `$parent.screenInfo.crDone`. However, I wouldn't advise doing it like this as it creates unnecessary coupling between scopes ... introducing a third `ng-if` would then require chaining scopes like `$parent.$parent` - messy.

Alternatively, you could use `ng-show` to control the visibility of components. This doesn't introduce a new scope so your code would work as expected ... regardless of the level of nesting.

Comment: Is an ng-show inside of a ng-if bound to the nested scope of the ng-if?  I changed `<div ng-if=...'><div<ng-if=...'></div></div>` to `<div ng-if=...'><div<ng-show=...'></div></div>` and the problem still persists.  I am thinking the nested ng-show is now bound to the ng-if's nested scope.  yes?

Comment: You're right. Any attempt to access `$scope` within an `ng-if` will use the scope of the `ng-if`. As such, the parent `ng-if` would have to be changed to an `ng-show` to preserve the scope.

Answer (score 0):

> In this sample i try to create nested `ng-if` with `ul` & `li`, please comment this post if i miss understanding the question

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope", "$sce",
  function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.parent = {
      active: false,
      childs: {
        child1: {
          active: false
        },
        child2: {
          active: false
        },
        child3: {
          active: false
        },
        child4: {
          active: false
        },
        child5: {
          active: false,
          childs: {
            child1: {
              active: false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $scope.status = function(active) {
      switch (active) {
        case "parent":
          $scope.parent.active = !$scope.parent.active;
          break;
        case "child1":
          $scope.parent.childs.child1.active = !$scope.parent.childs.child1.active;
          break;
        case "child2":
          $scope.parent.childs.child2.active = !$scope.parent.childs.child2.active;
          break;
        case "child3":
          $scope.parent.childs.child3.active = !$scope.parent.childs.child3.active;
          break;
        case "child4":
          $scope.parent.childs.child4.active = !$scope.parent.childs.child4.active;
          break;
        case "child5":
          $scope.parent.childs.child5.active = !$scope.parent.childs.child5.active;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-if="parent.active">
      Parent - has 5 childs
      <ul>
        <li ng-if="parent.active">child 1 (active: {{parent.childs.child1.active}}) <small class="text-info">(if parent active is true)</small></li>
        <li ng-if="parent.childs.child1.active">child 2 (active: {{parent.childs.child2.active}})<small class="text-info">(if <u>child 1</u> active is true)</small></li>
        <li ng-if="parent.childs.child1.active && parent.childs.child2.active">child 3 (active: {{parent.childs.child3.active}}) <small class="text-info">(if <u>child 1</u> & <u>child 2</u> active is true)</small></li>
        <li ng-if="parent.childs.child1.active && parent.childs.child2.active && parent.childs.child3.active">child 4 (active: {{parent.childs.child4.active}}) <small class="text-info">(if <u>child 1</u> & <u>child 2</u> & <u>child 3</u> active is true)</small></li>
        <li ng-if="parent.childs.child1.active && parent.childs.child2.active && parent.childs.child3.active && parent.childs.child4.active">
          child 5 (active: {{parent.childs.child5.active}}) <small class="text-info">(if <u>child 1</u> & <u>child 2</u> & <u>child 3</u> & <u>child 4</u> active is true)</small>
          <ul>
            <li ng-if="parent.childs.child1.active && parent.childs.child2.active && parent.childs.child3.active && parent.childs.child4.active && parent.childs.child5.active">child 5-1 (active: {{parent.childs.child5.childs.child1.active}}) <small class="text-info">(if <u>child 1</u> & <u>child 2</u> & <u>child 3</u> & <u>child 4</u> & <u>child 5</u> active is true)</small></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="status('parent')">{{parent.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Parent</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status('child1')">{{parent.childs.child1.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Child 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status('child2')">{{parent.childs.child2.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Child 2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status('child3')">{{parent.childs.child3.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Child 3</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status('child4')">{{parent.childs.child4.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Child 4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="status('child5')">{{parent.childs.child5.active ? 'Deactive':'Active'}} Child 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: revamped my original posting to include all the code.  I am still not getting this to work properly.